# シェルスクリプトから使える config ファイルの作り方

Tags: shellscript, shell

`command -p1 <param1> -p2 <param2> ...`

みたいなコマンドをデーモンでいくつか動かしたいのですが
**パラメータを１つの設定ファイルで管理する方法**はないでしょうか？

今は

```
#!/bin/bash
PARAM1=abc
PARAM2=123
command -p1 $PARAM1 -p2 $PARAM2
```

みたいなスクリプトをいくつも用意してるのですが
**パラメータを変更する際全部のファイルに変更が必要なので１ファイルに集約したい**です

例えば config.ini

```
[option1]
PARAM1: abc
PARAM2: 123

[option2]
PARAM1: def
PARAM2: 456
```

みたいな設定ファイルと

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# config.ini のラベル $1 を読み込み
command -p1 $PARAM1 -p2 $PARAM2
```

という共通の実行ファイルだけ用意して
`bash start.sh option1`
`bash start.sh option2`
みたいにラベル名だけ渡してパラメータを変えられるようにしたいです

設定ファイルのフォーマットは ini でも yaml でも２次元 hash を扱えれば何でもいいです

とりあえず設定ファイルを json にして
jq で .$1.PARAM1  .$1.PARAM2
みたいに取得することを考えてますが json ってコメントアウトができないので
もっと定番の方法があったら教えて欲しいです

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bashですよね。シンプルに `source` に引数を渡したらどうでしょうか。

#### start.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)
source "${CURRENT_DIR:?}/config.sh" "$1"

echo command -p1 "$PARAM1" -p2 "$PARAM2"
```

#### config.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
option1)
    PARAM1=abc
    PARAM2=123
    ;;
option2)
    PARAM1=def
    PARAM2=456
    ;;
esac
```

実行するとこんな感じ:

```
$ bash start.sh option1
command -p1 abc -p2 123
```

Comment: 確かに２次元ハッシュに拘ってましたが単に分岐するだけでよかったんですね。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

`config.ini` のフォーマットが質問欄にある通りだとして、sed を使って以下の様に書く事もできるでしょう。テストの意味で最後のコマンドの実行部分は echo の引数にしてあります。

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

eval $(
  sed -En '
    /^\['"$1"']/,/^$/{
      s/^[ \t]*([^:]+)[ \t]*:[ \t]*(.+)[ \t]*$/\1="\2"/p
    }
  ' < config.ini
)

echo command ${PARAM1:+-p1} "${PARAM1}" ${PARAM2:+-p2} "${PARAM2}"
```

**config.ini**

```
[option1]
PARAM1: abc
PARAM2: 123

[option2]
PARAM1: def
PARAM2: 456

[option3]
PARAM1: foo

[option4]
PARAM2: bar
```

**実行例**

```
$ ./start.sh option1
command -p1 abc -p2 123

$ ./start.sh option2
command -p1 def -p2 456

## PARAM1 のみ指定
$ ./start.sh option3
command -p1 foo 

## PARAM2 のみ指定
$ ./start.sh option4
command  -p2 bar

## option 指定なし
$ ./start.sh
command
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。sed があまりよくわかってないのですが、これで動くなら使わせてもらいます！　ただ sed ってOSによって複数あって動いたり動かなかったりするイメージなのですが大丈夫なんでしょうか。Mac と Amazon Linux でさえ挙動が同じならいいんですが

Comment: 一応、使用している正規表現に関しては ERE(Extended Regular Expressions) の範疇に収まっていますので問題はないはずです。ただ、このフォーマットの INI ファイルを厳密に扱うのであればシェルスクリプトよりは python や ruby などの LL の方が良いだろうとは思います(ライブラリが用意されていますので)。

Answer (score 1):

source(または.)コマンドを利用すれば
シンプルにシェルスクリプト内でシェルスクリプトを即時実行できます。
呼び出したシェルスクリプトの変数はそのまま使えます。

config.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
$PARAM1=abc
$PARAM2=123
```

cmd.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source ./config.sh

echo $PARAM1
echo $PARAM2
```

実行結果はこんな形です。

> $ ./cmd.sh
>   abc
>   123

あとは引数で切り分けで呼び出すオプション用のシェルを切り替えてはいかがでしょうか？

追記
sourceか.かはbashかそうじゃないかが大事になってきます。
適切な方を利用してみてください
（参考）
https://takuya-1st.hatenablog.jp/entry/2017/01/07/111105

Comment: config.sh から `$` を抜く必要があるのでは？

Comment: すみません。パラメータは１つのファイルで管理したいのです。これだと結局複数のパラメータファイルにわかれることになります

Answer (score 1):

よくあるのは、bash 形式の特定のファイルを読み込む方法だと思います。

ex) .bashrc

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

なので、引数を元にするなら以下のような感じでしょうか

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "${1}.conf" ]; then
  . "${1}.conf"
fi
command -p1 $PARAM1 -p2 $PARAM2
```

${1}.conf は、通常の bash 形式なので

option1.conf

```
PARAM1=abc
PARAM2=123
```

option2.conf

```
PARAM1=def
PARAM2=456
```

と、言う形になります。

```
# 全体で同じ設定をしたり
if [ -f "/etc/default/hoe.conf" ]; then
  . "/etc/default/hoe.conf"
fi

# コマンド毎の設定をしたり
if [ -f "${0}.conf" ]; then
  . "${0}.conf"
fi

# 引数でそれらの一部を変更したり
if [ -f "${1}.conf" ]; then
  . "${1}.conf"
fi

# 特定のディレクトリの物を見るようにしたり
if [ -f "/etc/myconf/${1}.conf" ]; then
  . "/etc/myconf/${1}.conf"
fi
```

と、ある程度柔軟にもできるので、お手軽だと思います。

１つの設定ファイルと言う条件にはならず、
オプション毎に設定ファイルが別になりますが、
複数の shell からは、同じオプション設定を読めます。

Comment: すみません。パラメータは１つのファイルで管理したいのです